# How to record websocket application using jmeter

Tags: websocket, jmeter

I have to test the performance of a 'Websocket Application'in Jmeter. But I didnt find any option to record using proxy server. How to record websocket application using jmeter

Answer (score 1):

I don't think WebSocket traffic is something you will be able to "record" as HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder is only capable of generating [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers and WebSocket protocol is a different beast.

In order to conduct WebSocket load testing you will need a custom [WebSocket Sampler](https://github.com/maciejzaleski/JMeter-WebSocketSampler) (it can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/))

[image: JMeter Plugins Manager WebSocket]

After installation you will see a brand new "WebSocket Sampler" which can be used for WebSocket requests generation. See [WebSocket Testing With Apache JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/websocket-testing-apache-jmeter) article for details.

Comment: I have added websocket sampler. But its so difficult to manually create websocket requests since the application is too complex. so how can i sort out this issue?

Comment: In JMeter it is not possible to record web socket traffic. In LR you can record using HTTP/HTML protocol. https://community.hpe.com/t5/LoadRunner-and-Performance/Async-Communications-The-WebSocket-protocol-made-easy-in/ba-p/6469242#.WO6RGPkrJpg